# UWP menu without hamburger

Tags: xaml, uwp

This is my first UWP app

I have a SplitView. On the right side I want a menu. On the left side I want to be able to load different pages into it(frame)

The only menu I can find have that hamburger in it(AppBarButton).

This app will only run on windows desktop machines so I do not have need of the hamburger and it will be rather useless.

I have spent the last two nights looking for options but all I get are hamburgers.

Can someone please point me to an example of a no hamburger menu or a tutorial of some kind?

I am sure I can figure it out once I know what elements to use, I just need a push in the correct direction.

Comment: Welcome to UWP and stackoverflow. You should attach a picture to show us what your `SplitView` looks like now. Also, it will be clear with the picture what type of "Menu" you actually want. UWP currently doesn't provide any control for HamburgerMenu. I think you are referring to a community toolkit control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is a base page (let's call it "HostView") this will simply have a `SplitView` control with the `DisplayMode` set to `Inline` and the `IsPaneOpen` set to `true`. You can also set the side panel width by using the `OpenPaneLength` property.

Your menu buttons go into the `SplitView.Pane` and you place a `Frame` control in the `SplitView.Content`. This frame will navigate to the correct page when a menu item is selected.

If you set the properties as I said above then you will not need a Hamburger menu to open the side panel at all. However, please consider the fact that users will want to resize your app, and they might resize to a very narrow size which means it might not have enough space to display all the content. IN which case you will need to collapse the side panel and show a hamburger menu to open it when needed. You don't have to do this, but it is something to consider.

Comment: Thanks for the help. What would I use for the menu item? I just want about 6 menu items going down the left side. with no hamburger.

Comment: @mooch201 a simple stackpanel will do for your menu. Make sure to set the Orientation to vertical (this is the default anyways)